# mongodb query for or operator

Tags: mongodb

As in ravendb Or operation are not available we have a query in ravendb. iwant the expression to be written in mongodb query using Query.Or

```
  var customerIdExpression = string.Format("CustomerId:({0})", string.Join(" OR "item.CustomerId));
```

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question. Do you want to use a logical or in the query expression? or do you want to contains type query. Please provide a little more information for clarity

Comment: i want the query where Query.Or is used.

Comment: somehting like: `var or = []; for(i in items){ var or[or.length-1]={CustomerId: items[i].CustomerId}; } db.col.find({$or: or});` is what your asking for aint it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knocked together a test app that is my interpretation of what you are looking for:

```
var item = new {CustomerId = "123"};
var item2 = new { CustomerId = "123" };
var query1 = new QueryDocument("CustomerId", item.CustomerId);
var query2 = new QueryDocument("CustomerId", item2.CustomerId);
var logicalOrBetweenSubQueries = Query.Or(query1,query2);
```

If this is what your looking for I can't but think there might be a better way to achieve set membership semantics. Something like this might be useful:

```
var membership = Query.In("CustomerId", new[] { BsonValue.Create(item.CustomerId), BsonValue.Create(item2.CustomerId)});
```

All predicated on my understanding of your problem.

Hope this helps

p.s. some links

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/or/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/